# Using Twilio Flex Plugin, how do I update the current voice task attribute so that customer name shows in TaskListItem?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I would like to know how I can update the task attribute so that the customer name is set to whatever name I want, instead of the E.164 formatted phone. 
[image]

I would like to invoke the setter from within the plugin init

```
init(flex, manager) {
```

I imagine this is a common use case that customers would like. How can I accomplish this? 
Where exactly are these attributes set?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I after accepting the task, you just need to run

```
            flex.DefaultTaskChannels.Call.templates.TaskListItem.firstLine = matchingCustomerName;
            flex.DefaultTaskChannels.Call.templates.TaskCanvasHeader.title = matchingCustomerName;
            flex.DefaultTaskChannels.Call.templates.CallCanvas.firstLine = matchingCustomerName;
            flex.ParticipantCanvas.Content.replace(<h3 key="name">{matchingCustomerName}</h3>);
```

Comment: I know it's been awhile, but how did you access `matchingCustomerName` in plugin init?